# PropertyInfo.SetValue unable to convert string to Decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable which has columns of different datatypes(mostly int64 and string).
I am trying to convert this datatable into list of objects.
For which i am using these methods,

```
public static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)
{
 List<T> data = new List<T>();
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
  T item = GetItem<T>(row);
  data.Add(item);
 }
 return data;
}
```

The below GetItem()(`pro.SetValue()` to be more precise) method throws an exception(`Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'`.) when trying to convert the `datacolumn` value which is of `string` to the class property of type `Decimal`

```
private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
{
 Type temp = typeof(T);
 T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
 foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
 {
  foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
  {
   if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
    pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
    else
     continue;
  }
 }
return obj;
}
```

Here  is `MyClass`
Which is nothing but

```
public class AgriSales
{
 public Int64 Id { get; set; }
 public string Type { get; set; }
 public Decimal Cost    { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone guide me the right way to overcome the hurdle that i am facing?

Comment: You need to tell us what exception is thrown.

Comment: Updated my post as per your suggestion Richard. It throws ArgumentException which says , Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) could help you out. However you might need to implment same safeguards for more complex types.

```
pro.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(dr[column.ColumnName], pro.PropertyType), null);
```